# JOOQ - How i can fetch data into pojo with a field list

Tags: java, jooq

I have a DDBB with three tables: loan, person and loan_person_rel and the respective POJO for each table.

Loan

```
private int line;
private Double balance;
private Double expired;
private int state;
private int defaultDays;
private Branch branch;
private String balanceHistory;
private String expiredHistory;
private Long loanCode;
private List<Person> persons;
private String extraInfo;
private LoanTypes loanType;
private String nomPro;
//The class contains the getters and setters :)
```

Person

```
private String name;
private String documentNumber;
private String workEnterprise;
private String workCity;
private String workAddress;
private String workNeighborhood;
private String workPhone;
private String occupation;
private String homePhone;
private String cellPhone;
private String phone3;
private String phone4;
private String homeAddress;
private String homeCity;
private String homeNeighborhood;
private String email;
private String relationship;
private List<Loan> loans;
//The class contains the getters and setters :)
```

Loan_person_rel

```
private String personId;
private String loanId;
private int type;
//The class contains the getters and setters :)
```

How i can build a JOOQ select or some method for retrieve the data and fill the class loan with the field `persons` populated?

Comment: What you asking here looks like you need a full-blown ORM solution, not JOOQ. JOOQ is relatively simple SQL mapper/generator library, not a model graph query tool. Or at least this was always my impression.

Comment: If for some reason you really *must not* use a JPA-based entity graph persistence framework, you might be able to pull this off using jOOQ and something like http://simpleflatmapper.org/0106-getting-started-jooq.html. But usually, it's much simple to embrace SQL and work with what the JPA folks call "projections" (i.e. just plain SQL) and not worry about nesting collections too much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### jOOQ 3.15 solutoin using `MULTISET`

Starting [with jOOQ 3.15, the standard SQL `MULTISET` operator was introduced](https://blog.jooq.org/2021/07/06/jooq-3-15s-new-multiset-operator-will-change-how-you-think-about-sql/), which is emulated using SQL/XML or SQL/JSON if needed. For simplicity, I'm assuming your `Loan` and `Person` classes are Java 16 records:

```java
List<Loan> result =
ctx.select(
      // Project the loan columns you need
      LOAN.LINE,
      LOAN.BALANCE,
      ..
      multiset(
        select(PERSON.NAME, PERSON.DOCUMENT_NUMBER, ...)
        .from(PERSON)
        .join(LOAN_PERSON_REL)
        .on(PERSON.PERSON_ID.eq(LOAN.PERSON_REL.PERSON_ID))
        .where(LOAN_PERSON_REL.LOAN_ID.eq(LOAN.LOAN_ID))
      ).as("persons").convertFrom(r -> r.map(Records.mapping(Person::new)))
   )
   .from(LOAN)
   .fetch(Records.mapping(Loan::new));
```

The mapping into the `Loan` and `Person` constructor references is type safe and reflection free, using the [new jOOQ 3.15 ad-hoc converter feature](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/fetching/ad-hoc-converter/).

Unlike JPA based ORMs, jOOQ doesn't offer object *graph* persistence, i.e. your `Person` objects can't contain identity-based references back to `Loan` objects. Instead, this approach projects data in tree form, which may be fine for your use-cases.

#### jOOQ 3.14 solution using SQL/XML or SQL/JSON

Starting with jOOQ 3.14, the preferred approach here is to [nest your collections directly in SQL using SQL/XML or SQL/JSON](https://blog.jooq.org/2020/10/09/nesting-collections-with-jooq-3-14s-sql-xml-or-sql-json-support/). You could write a query like this:

```java
List<Loan> result =
ctx.select(
      // Project the loan columns you need, or all of them using LOAN.asterisk()
      LOAN.LINE,
      LOAN.BALANCE,
      ...
      field(select(
        jsonArrayAgg(jsonObject(
          key("name").value(PERSON.NAME),
          key("documentNumber").value(PERSON.DOCUMENT_NUMBER),
          ...
        ))
        .from(PERSON)
        .join(LOAN_PERSON_REL)
        .on(PERSON.PERSON_ID.eq(LOAN.PERSON_REL.PERSON_ID))
        .where(LOAN_PERSON_REL.LOAN_ID.eq(LOAN.LOAN_ID))
      )).as("persons")
    )
   .from(LOAN)
   .fetchInto(Loan.class);
```

The same restriction about this fetching trees instead of graphs applies.

Note that `JSON_ARRAYAGG()` aggregates empty sets into `NULL`, not into an empty `[]`. [If that's a problem, use `COALESCE()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67932476/521799)

Answer (score 1):

It must be so way:

```
List<Loan*> list = dsl.selectFrom(Loan).fetch(this::recordToPojo);

private Loan recordToPojo(final LoanRecord record) {
    return new Loan(
            record.getLine(),
            record.getBalance(),
            ....
    );
}
```

*Loan - name of pojo!